# What is the best way to express the set of sets that has no element in common with another set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am trying to express the following: I have a set $A$ and the powerset (set of all subsets of $A$) $P(A)$. I have another set $S \in P(A)$, and I want to get the sets in $P(A)$ with no element in common with $S$.

The way I express this is $$X \in P(A): X \cap S = \{\}$$

Is there a more concise way or a special notation from set theory?

Comment: Isn't it $P(A\setminus S)$?

Comment: Symmetric Set Difference: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Answer (score 2):

So $P(A\setminus S)$ could do the job ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use union of disjoint subsets to achieve the same thing: $X, Y \in P(A), X \sqcup Y \equiv A$

Comment: This is called the symmetric difference I believe